# how can i convert large, custom xml data into entities in symfony2

Tags: xml, symfony

In our symfony2 app, we have some xml data about 60mb and i have to:

1. read that xml file
2. parse the xml file
3. map parsed xml data into our entities
4. and save all of our entities.

Moreover, the xml files can vary. I mean their structure is not standard. I have to map them custom. I researched and found Jms Serializer, Eko/FeedBundle etc. but i think none of them are usable for me in my situation.

Which bundle do you prefer or, are there any bundle that solves my problems. Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, the xml files can vary. I mean their structure is not standard* How can you guess the association between the data and the entities if the files vary? I don't think there is a bundle which can parse your XML file and magically translate it to entities. It's more a PHP problem than a Symfony2-specific problem.

Comment: PHP provides the functions for 1. and 2. and Doctrine2 will handle the 4. For 3. you'll have to write your own code.

Comment: i am not waiting some magicall stuff. Just making parsing varied xml data into entities is enough. And i think i found it: https://github.com/mathielen/import-engine/blob/master/README.md

Comment: so I was wrong, it looks like this bundle fits your needs, it's really interesting. A [Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/mathielen/ImportEngineBundle) is also available.

Comment: thanks for your consideration. there is nothing wrong about being wrong :)